# Vary xytext to prevent overlapping annotations

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

So I've got some code that generates a donut chart but the problem is there are cases where the annotations overlap due to the values. Code and problem below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def donut_chart(val):

    df_vals = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(val, orient='index')
    labels = df_vals.index.tolist()

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))

    color = ['grey']*20
    color[0] = 'red'

    wedges, texts, junk = ax.pie(df_vals[0:4], counterclock = True, 
                            wedgeprops=dict(width=0.6, linewidth = 2, edgecolor = 'w'), 
                           startangle=90, colors=color,
                           autopct='%1.0f%%',
                           pctdistance=0.75,
                           textprops={'fontsize': 14})

    bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="w", lw=0.72)
    kw = dict(xycoords='data', textcoords='data', arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-"),
              bbox=bbox_props, zorder=0, va="center")

    for i, p in enumerate(wedges):
        ang = (p.theta2 - p.theta1)/2. + p.theta1
        y = np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang))
        x = np.cos(np.deg2rad(ang))
        horizontalalignment = {-1: "right", 1: "left"}[int(np.sign(x))]
        connectionstyle = "angle,angleA=0,angleB={}".format(int(ang))
        kw["arrowprops"].update({"connectionstyle": connectionstyle})
        ax.annotate(labels[i], xy=(x, y), xytext=(1.2*np.sign(x), 1.2*y),
                     horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment, **kw, size=14)

    #centre_circle = plt.Circle((0,0),0.5, fc='white',linewidth=1.25)
    #fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.show()
    plt.close()


val = {'Label A':50, 'Label B':2, 'Label C':1, 'Label D':0.5}
donut_chart(val)
```

Problem:

[image]

What I'd like to do is create something like this:

[image]

The key appears to be varying the y value in the xytext so the labels don't overlap but I'm stuck on how this might be implemented or even whether it is possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

**updated code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def donut_chart(val):

    df_vals = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(val, orient='index')
    labels = df_vals.index.tolist()

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))

    color = ['grey']*20
    color[0] = 'red'

    wedges, texts = ax.pie(df_vals[0:5], counterclock = True, 
                            wedgeprops=dict(width=0.6, linewidth = 1, edgecolor = 'w'), 
                           startangle=90, colors=color,
                           textprops={'fontsize': 14})

    bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0", fc="w", ec="w", lw=0.72)
    kw = dict(xycoords='data', textcoords='data', arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-"),
              bbox=bbox_props, zorder=0, va="center")

    for i, p in enumerate(wedges):
        ang = (p.theta2 - p.theta1)/2. + p.theta1
        y = np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang))
        x = np.cos(np.deg2rad(ang))
        horizontalalignment = {-1: "right", 1: "left"}[int(np.sign(x))]
        connectionstyle = "angle,angleA=0,angleB={}".format(int(ang))
        kw["arrowprops"].update({"connectionstyle": connectionstyle})
        ax.annotate(labels[i], xy=(x, y), xytext=((i/10) + 1.1*np.sign(x), (i/10) + y),
                     horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment, **kw, size=14)

    #centre_circle = plt.Circle((0,0),0.5, fc='white',linewidth=1.25)
    #fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
val = {'Label A':50, 'Label B':2, 'Label C':0.2, 'Label D':0.2,'Label E':0.2}
donut_chart(val)
```

**difference**

```
 ax.annotate(labels[i], xy=(x, y), xytext=((i/10) + 1.1*np.sign(x), (i/10) + y),
                     horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment, **kw, size=14)
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvYXo.png)